# How to manage hasMany relations which come up as empty from form? (CakePHP 3.x)

Tags: php, cakephp, database-relations

I have tables on database. Venues, Venue Coordinators. Venue might have multiple coordinators. I have a form to save venue and its coordinators. But venues must be saved without coordinator infos sometimes. However when I do that, cakephp warns me: "Coordinator cannot be empty". Because yes, coordinator cannot be. But if coordinator inputs both are empty, I would like to ignore on table-side / event-side.

For example I tried to delete it by using beforeMarshal() on Table object. didn't work.

```
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options)
    {
        if ($data['full_name'] == '' && $data['phone_number'] == '') {
            unset($data);
        }
    }
```

**I want to do:**

When I fill the venue form with coordinator input, it saves properly.
When I fill the venue form without coordinator input. it saves venue properly without coordinator. Because coordinators are not necessary.

[image]

Comment: Please show what exactly you've tried, and what the conflicting validation rules look like. Deleting empty datasets in the `beforeMarshal` event is a solution that generally works.

Comment: @ndm I add to post my beforeMarshal code. please check it out what's wrong.

Comment: From the looks of it, that code is located in the `VenueCoordinatorsTable` class?

Comment: Exactly there is @ndm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `unset()` call will not affect the data at all, that's not how PHP works, all this does is unsetting a variable in the local scope of the `beforeMarshal()` method.

You must unset the actual association property/key from within the parent table, ie in `VenuesTable::beforeMarshal()`. Something along the lines of:

```
if (isset($data['venue_coordinators']) &&
    is_array($data['venue_coordinators']) &&
    count($data['venue_coordinators']) === 1 &&

    (!isset($data['venue_coordinators'][0]['full_name']) ||
    $data['venue_coordinators'][0]['full_name'] === '')  &&

    (!isset($data['venue_coordinators'][0]['phone_number']) ||
    $data['venue_coordinators'][0]['phone_number'] === '')
) {
    unset($data['venue_coordinators']);
}
```

See also

- **[PHP Manual > Function Reference > Unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)**
- **[PHP Manual > Language Reference > Variables > Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**

Comment: I just tried this. It makes sense and worked for me. Thanks. @ndm